# Disabling a control inside jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable a ddl (ddlGender) inside my jQuery UI Dialog with Javascript but it doesn't work, also tried from code-behind as well, please advice. Thanks:

```
 function loadDialog() {
       var gender = $('#<%=litGender.ClientID %>').val();
       if (gender != '') {
           alert('true');
           $('#<%=ddlGender.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
       }
        $('#DialogBox').dialog('open');
    }



 <div id="DialogBox" title="">
     <span>Gender:</span><asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGender" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
                                                                                       onselectedindexchanged="ddlGender_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                                                         <asp:ListItem Text="Both" Value="" Selected = "True"/>
                                                                         <asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="m"/>
                                                                         <asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="f" /> 
                                                                     </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Comment: you can add a `hidden` jquery css class like this `document.getElementById("DialogBox").className='ui-helper-hidden';` and remove that class when not required

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method for this:

```
$('#<%=ddlPref.ClientID %>').attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
```

Answer (score 1):

[$()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) returns a jQuery object, not a DOM element. You can either use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$("#<%=ddlPref.ClientID %>").prop("disabled", true);
```

Or work on the DOM element itself:

```
$("#<%=ddlPref.ClientID %>")[0].disabled = true;
```